# Why is "time orthogonal to space" in inertial reference frames?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, vectors

I'm reading about the geometry of spacetime in special relativity (ref. Core Principles of Special and General Relativity by Luscombe). Here's the relevant section:

> Minkowski space is a four-dimensional vector space (with points in one-to-one correspondence with those of $\mathbb{R}^4$) spanned by one timelike basis vector, $\vec e_t$, and three spacelike basis vectors, $\vec e_x, \vec e_y, \vec e_z$. **While any four linearly independent vectors can constitute a basis, in IRFs we require time to be orthogonal to space**.

I'm not clear what is meant by this. By "time", does the author mean the $[1,0,0,0]$ basis vector and by "space", does he mean the $[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]$ basis vectors? If that's the case, this is no different from the Euclidean $\mathbb{R}^4$ case - I could've just said that "we require $x$ to be orthogonal to the other dimensions", where by "$x$" I mean the corresponding standard basis vector. So I'm guessing that's not what the author meant.

If by "time" and "space" the author isn't referring to corresponding standard basis vectors, then I'm not sure what's stopping me from taking an arbitrary basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$ as a basis of Minkowski Space as well. Why do we *require* "time" to be orthogonal to "space"? (whatever the quoted words mean in this context) What is even meant by the statement?

Is there a proper mathematical justification for this?

Comment: _By "time", does the author mean the $[1,0,0,0]$ basis vector and by "space", does he mean the $[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]$ basis vectors?_ You need to be careful about what is meant by those components. The bases are one-forms not vectors. So to write them in component form, you need to decide on some other bases which are vectors. What is that presumed bases for your claim?

Comment: @DvijD.C. : You're right, I think it's a bit reckless of me to write out the components without specifying a basis first. I'm not an expert at this, but I don't see how the vector components are the same as one-forms (which I'm guessing are the same as linear functionals?). From what I understand, the basis functionals or covectors would look like $\vec e^t, \vec e^x, \vec e^y, \vec e^z$, where $\vec e^i(\vec e_j)=\eta^i_j$ (the Minkowski metric). That's about as far as my understanding goes.

Comment: Your understanding looks correct but notice that you need a basis made of covectors to write vectors in component form (and vice-versa). You can't produce numbers out of vectors simply by using other vectors, you need covectors for that (and again, vice versa).

Comment: @DvijD.C. : Hmm fair enough. But were you able to understand what the author means in this context? How do we prove that time is orthogonal to space? Does this phrase have a concrete meaning or is it an ill-posed statement?